# Execute excel vba macro from within powershell, for loop inside macro doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am trying to execute an Excel VBA macro from within powershell.
Inside the macro I am using a for loop to delete some wrong values inside the excel cells.
The loop is not executed by powershell, but if I run the macro inside the VBA editor it works fine.

Please find my code below:

---

### Code from Powershell:

```
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application                                   $objMisVal = [System.Reflection.Missing]::Value                                                                                                           
$xlsdoc = "C:\Path\ExcelFile.xlsm"
$sheetname = "XXX"
$makro = "formatanpassungen"                       
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($xlsdoc, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, `
$objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, `
$objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal, $objMisVal)                                   

$excel.visible = $true

$excel.run($makro)                                 

$Workbook|Get-Member *Save*
$workbook.Save()
```

---

### Code from Excel VBA:

```
Sub formatanpassungen()
Dim iZeile As Integer
Dim sRechnungsNrOLD As String
Dim sRechnungsNrNEW As String

'ganzes Arbeitsblatt nach doppelten Rechnungsnummern durchsuchen
For i = 4 To iZeile

    If Sheets("XXX").Cells(i, 9) = 0 Then GoTo 10

    'Ermittlung RG-Nr OLD
    If i >= 5 Then sRechnungsNrOLD = Sheets("XXX").Cells(i - 1, 9)

    'Ermittlung RG-Nr NEW
    sRechnungsNrNEW = Sheets("XXX").Cells(i, 9)

    'Wenn RG-NrNEW = RG-NrOLD, then....
    If sRechnungsNrNEW = sRechnungsNrOLD Then
        Sheets("XXX").Cells(i, 14) = ""
        Sheets("XXX").Cells(i, 15) = ""
    End If

10:

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your macro loops using ```For i = 4 To iZeile``` but I can't see where you set the value of ```iZeile```, so it's possibly using ```0``` by default which would mean it doesn't enter the body of the ```For```.

Comment: Hi mclayton, i forgot to paste the line ```iZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row```. the original code is much longer. i try to paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

the code below is now working, but not the complete code.

```
' Aktualisieren Makro

Dim iZeile As Integer
Dim sRechnungsNrOLD As String
Dim sRechnungsNrNEW As String

iZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("I4:I" & iZeile)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

'Formatanpassungen
iZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To iZeile

    If Sheets("xxx").Cells(i, 9) = 0 Then GoTo 10

    'Ermittlung RG-Nr OLD
    If i >= 5 Then sRechnungsNrOLD = Sheets("xxx").Cells(i - 1, 9)

    'Ermittlung RG-Nr NEW
    sRechnungsNrNEW = Sheets("xxx").Cells(i, 9)

    'Wenn RG-NrNEW = RG-NrOLD, dann....
    If sRechnungsNrNEW = sRechnungsNrOLD Then
        Sheets("xxx").Cells(i, 14) = ""
        Sheets("xxx").Cells(i, 15) = ""
    End If

10:

Next i

'Alle Pivot-Tabellen aktualisieren
Sheets("ÜBERSICHT_Alle").Select
Range("A7").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("xxx").Select

End Sub
```